# Error in mapping models with Automapper C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

For some reason mapping is not working. I set up mapping configuration to take Id (Guid) from TopicModel and map it to UId (Guid) of Topic, but it still tries to map Id (Guid) to Id (int).

Getting error here:

```
    private class PostTopicsResolver : IValueResolver<CreatePostModel, Post, ICollection<Topic>>
    {
        public ICollection<Topic> Resolve(CreatePostModel source, Post destination, ICollection<Topic> member, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return context.Mapper.Map<ICollection<Topic>>(source.Topics);
        }
    }
```

Here is how I am trying to map:

```
public class TopicModel
{
    public required Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class TopicModelProfile : Profile
{
    public TopicModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TopicModel, Topic>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Uid, opt =>
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));

        CreateMap<Topic, TopicModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt =>
                opt.MapFrom(src => src.Uid));
    }
}
```

I tried to map both way. I tried to put the mapping configuration of TopicModel into CreatePostModel, but nothing helped.

Class:

```
public class Topic : BaseEntity
{
  public required string Type { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

[Index("Uid", IsUnique = true)]
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public virtual Guid Uid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add an explicit Ignore config for the id property that is not supposed to be mapped?

Comment: @Fildor, tried, it did actually help. But why it did not follow the mapping rules I have written?

Comment: The PostTopicsResolver class is attempting to map a collection of TopicModel to a collection of Topic. It’s crucial that the mapping for the collection types is properly defined. If not, AutoMapper might be defaulting to its built-in logic which could be causing the issue with the Id property.

If the collection mapping is not explicitly defined, consider defining it. AutoMapper should handle collections automatically, but if there's a problem, being explicit can help:
CreateMap<ICollection<TopicModel>, ICollection<Topic>>();